Get the List Items which are Not in the string value
I am looking for a way to find out the items in the List<> which are not in the string value. I have a list<> of items as shown below :
            List<DoorDetails> ListDoorData = new List<DoorDetails>();

            DoorDetails dm = new DoorDetails();
            dm.door_id = 1;
            dm.brand = "BM";
            dm.buying_group = "Silly USA";
            dm.setting_name = "Settings1";
            dm.datamodel = 13;
            dm.tracking_weeks = 1;

            DoorDetails dm1 = new DoorDetails();
            dm1.door_id = 2;
            dm1.brand = "NB";
            dm1.buying_group = "John USA";
            dm1.setting_name = "Settings2";
            dm1.datamodel = 16;
            dm1.tracking_weeks = 14;

            DoorDetails dm11 = new DoorDetails();
            dm11.door_id = 3; ;
            dm11.brand = "JA";
            dm11.buying_group = "Mathew UK";
            dm11.setting_name = "Settings3";
            dm11.datamodel = 17;
            dm11.tracking_weeks = 45;

            ListDoorData.Add(dm);
            ListDoorData.Add(dm1);
            ListDoorData.Add(dm11); 

I have a string which has a value like as shown below:
           string filterstr = "NB|JA";

I want to get the "brand" of all items which are not in the "filterstr".
That means, below is the object whose "brand" property is not "NB" and "JA",
            DoorDetails dm = new DoorDetails();
            dm.door_id = 1;
            dm.brand = "BM";
            dm.buying_group = "Silly USA";
            dm.setting_name = "Settings1";
            dm.datamodel = 13;
            dm.tracking_weeks = 1;

(Sometimes the variable "filterstr" contains more values like)
            NB|JA|WS|AM

I have tried the below code....but it is not getting the exact result.
          for (int i = 0; i < ListDoorData.Count(); i++)
            {
               if (!FilterStr.Contains(ListDoorData[i].GetType().GetProperty(FilterOrder)?.GetValue(ListDoorData[i])?.ToString()))
                {
                    ListDoorData.Remove(ListDoorData[i]);
                }
            }

where "FilterOrder" can be the "DoorDetails" class property like "brand", "buying_group" or "setting_name", etc
Please help me to get the List<> of Items which are not in the string value ???
Thanks.

Why exactly are you using reflection? That seems unnecessary.

First you need to split your filter items, then you can use Linq's Contains
string[] filterItems = filterstr.Split('|');
var filteredData = ListDoorData
    .Where(d => !filterItems.Contains(d.brand));

If you want to filter the original list, you could either create a new:
ListDoorData = filteredData.ToList();

or use List.RemoveAll, which i'd prefer in this case:
ListDoorData.RemoveAll(d => filterItems.Contains(d.brand));


@KitKat and if you need this for more string-typed properties, then you could make an extension method that takes a Func<DoorDetails, string> to select the property to filter by.

Hi @Tim Schmelter Thanks for the reply. Is there any generic way to use like ListDoorData.RemoveAll(d => filterItems.Contains(FilterOrder)); Because the same filtering method can be used for different properties like "buying_group" or "setting_name" or "datamodel", etc. The variable FilterOrder can be any of these properties. Is there any way ???

Yes. Make FilterOrder a Func<DoorDetails, string> and call ListDoorData.RemoveAll(d => filterItems.Contains(FilterOrder(d))); that means you just need a delegate that takes a DoorDetail and return the respective string.

@Fildor Hi, If you don't mind could you please elaborate your answer in the answer column ??? I didn't understand it.

@KitKat: i don't understand it. You have to know somewhere that you want to filter by a specific property, there you can use it, for example: ListDoorData.RemoveAll(d => filterItems.Contains(d.buying_group));

@Fildor: i'd rename the extension to RemoveBy, otherwise someone would think that the filter items are searched

@TimSchmelter You are right ... on the other hand, it was just meant to be a scribble showcasing what OP could do. And as it is merely a "cherry on top", maybe it's better to add it to this perfectly fine answer?

Improved example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h933h6
